# ETW File IO Monitoring on XP/2003

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2003, etw

I've been investigating ETW for process/file/registry/network monitoring. It looks like it on Win7 it has everything I need. However, on XP it seems to be lacking the same level of detail. Specifcally, with file IO only "FileCreate" events seem to be logged and process creation events don't give a full path.

Is it possible to determine when a file is written to on XP with ETW? And how about the full path to a process start event?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Vista MS added a lot of ETW providers to Windows. XP/Server only had a few of them. So you can't fix this for XP.

Comment: Damn. I guess I will be forced to write a minifilter driver then! :(

Comment: why do you still need XP support? It will be EOL next year.